# How does the radial component of acceleration not change the linear speed of a body in circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

All the sources I have read from say that radial component of acceleration of a body in circular motion only accounts for the change in direction . I do not understand how this is possible. Another thing I do not understand is what provides the torque for such a body to rotate. Could you please explain to me the forces and accelerations involved using the classic ball-and-rope example?

Comment: There are extremely many different expositions on this topic; you should at least tell us which ones you have put in effort into understanding and why they are not good enough for you. As for "what provides the torque", a body that is undergoing uniform circular motion is not under any torque. It simply is not necessary, contrary to what you think.

Comment: To the second part of your comment, a body does not have to necessarily rotate as it revolves. Its orientation can be fixed relative to a direction. So there has to be some force that causes the body to rotate about its axis, whether you call it torque or something else

Comment: You are making an elementary mistake. You need to realise that the Newton's 1st Law, concept of inertia, applies here.

Comment: Could you elaborate

Comment: Remember N1L! Something that is already moving, will continue in its motion without the need for forces and torques to maintain said motion. It was rotating, it will just continue rotating unless something robs it of the angular momentum. That you think that rotation needs torque to maintain is itself a pre-Newtonian kind of thinking.

Comment: You have misunderstood me. In my doubt I am alluding to the observation that a ball tied to a rope engaging in circular motion i.e. revolution about a fixed axis also seems to be undergoing an inherent rotation. In other words, the revolution is nothing but rotation about an axis that is a non-zero distance from the centre of mass. This becomes apparent if you imagine slowly reducing the radius of the ball to zero - the ball then undergoed pure rotation with its centre of mass on the axis.

Comment: My question is, why does the rotation seem to be an inherent part of the ball's circular motion? After all, I can imagine a ball revolving arond an axis with a fixed orientation. So where does the 'torque' that causes this rotation, as opposed to a circular motion where the ball's orientation is fixed, arise from? It must be due to the centipetal force, since that is the net force on the body, but how exactly?

Comment: The torque needed to setup this initial rotation is outside the scope of uniform circular motion. It is the part that happens before that. You are barking up the wrong tree. If you want to study that, you have to approach the problem completely else, and you should only do that after you have first understood uniform circular motion properly.

Comment: You are wrong. All the ball needs to commence uniform circular motion is a velocity and a centrapital force perpendicular to the velocity. Somehow it is the centripetal force that inherently causes rotation. I still don't quite understand how. It is not a question of how the ball rotates - you can only ask where the torque comes from if the ball maintains its orientation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be easier to show this the other way around: what is the acceleration of a ball going in circle at a given speed $v$ ?

A ball going at a speed $v$ on a circle with radius $R$ turns at an angular frequency $\omega = v/R$.

Let's try to parametrize the trajectory of our ball:

$$
x(t) = R cos(\omega t) \qquad y(t) = R sin(\omega t)
$$

The velocity is the derivative of position with respect to time so we get:

$$
v_x(t) = - \omega R sin(\omega t) \qquad v_y(t) = \omega R cos(\omega t)
$$

As you can see the intensity of the velocity is constant since

$$
|v| = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2} = \sqrt{\omega^2 R^2 (cos^2(\omega t) + sin^2(\omega t))} =  \sqrt{\omega^2 R^2} = \omega R = \frac{v}{R}R = v
$$

The acceleration is the derivative of the speed with respect to time so we get:

$$
a_x(t) = - \omega^2 R cos(\omega t) \qquad a_y(t) = - \omega^2 R sin(\omega t)
$$

Again, the intensity of this acceleration is constant since

$$
|a| = \sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2} = \sqrt{\omega^4 R^2 (cos^2(\omega t) + sin^2(\omega t))} =  \sqrt{\omega^4 R^2} = \omega^2 R = \frac{v^2}{R^2}R = \frac{v^2}{R}
$$

So you can see that it is mathematically possible to have an acceleration and a velocity which have both constant intensity but whose direction change in time.

Acceleration describes a change in velocity, the thing is that velocity is a vectorial quantity, so even if its magnitude stays constant but its direction changes, we have a change of this vectorial quantity and hence an acceleration.

Note that the velocity and acceleration are in this case orthogonal since $a_x v_x + a_y v_y = 0$, and hence the acceleration always points toward the center of the circle.

When you swing a ball attached to a rope, you have indeed a tension in the rope which induces a radial acceleration toward the center of the circle. The faster you swing the ball the bigger this acceleration will be, which you can see in the equation that we derived: $|a| = v^2/R$

Please tell me if some mathematical steps are too complicated or if you need clarification on a specific point.

EDIT: I noticed that you mentioned that there was a troque on the ball undergoing uniforme circular motion, which is wrong. Torque might be a word that you use in your everyday language to describe "was makes things rotate", but in physics the torque has a very specific definition. A torque is was makes the angular frequency change over time, or what changes the orbit of your rotation over time. In your rope-ball example, the angular frequency and the orbit stay the same, there is hence **no torque**. There is **only a force** which makes the ball rotate, which is called centripetal force. Here is [a link](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/10-7-newtons-second-law-for-rotation#:%7E:text=If%20more%20than%20one%20torque,i%20%CF%84%20i%20%3D%20I%20%CE%B1%20.) on the effect of torque on a rotating system.

Comment: Although I cannot say I can 'fathom' this, as it were, the mathematics certainly proves it, and so I must accept your explanation. Perhaps I will be able to reconcile with this fact some other day. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I can suggest you to check "essence of calculus" on YouTube to understand the mathematics of derivatives. This is the only math which was used in my explanation. I would also suggest you to check again the definition of torque, as I said in the edit of my post.

Answer (score 0):

1.Acceleration is defined as rate of change of velocity. In this case, suppose you have constant magnitude of velocity. However, centripetal force is still required for the object to continue moving in circular orbit, since the direction of velocity vector changes every second. That continuous change in direction of velocity is accomodated by the radial acceleration.
2. Torque is not necessary for circular motion, you're confusing it with centripetal force.
Centripetal force=mv²/r;
Radial acceleration=F/m=v²/r

Comment: Torque is necessary for a body to rotate around an axis. Typically, an object in circular motion, such as a ball attached to a string, rotates as well as revolves. Perhaps I should have specified I was talking about the type of circular motion where both kinds of motion are present.